# Add Existing Project into TFS2010

Tags: asp.net, tfs

I have configured TFS server with all credential for individual project collection. Now i can create a project in team foundation.It's correctly added in TFS server. But i can't added the existing source using (Add solution to source control).

```
TFS206018: The items could not be added to source control because either no team projects have been setup,or because you do not have permission to access any of the team projects in the current collection.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a "Team" project, rather than just a project.  If not then you need to do that first.  If you're using TFS online then you can do it via that, alternatively, in Visual Studio, select New -> Team Project.

You should then be able to add your solution to the team project that you've created.